# Linq to SQL Group by and sum in select with entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

This is mysql query:

```
select 
    convert(date,convert(char(11),[Bill Date])) as date,
    SUM(Amount) as total from Bills
group by [Bill Date]
order by date asc
```

What will be its LINQ to SQL with entitiy?

Comment: What is the type of `Bill Date` ?  I am curious why you are doing the convert call ?

Comment: 'Bill Date' is datetime. I need to change to take into chart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ `GroupBy` method with `Sum` method

You may use the `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` method on the BillDate datetime field to eliminate the timestamp part when grouping on the date (*assuming you want to get total for each day*)

```
var groupedSum= db.Bills.GroupBy(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.BillDate))
                  .Select(x => new
                                 {
                                     Total= x.Sum(g => g.Amount),
                                     Date = x.Key
                                 }).OrderBy(f=>f.Date).ToList();
```

This gives you a list of anonymous objects with a `Day` property and a `Total` property.

Assuming `db` is your db context object and `Bills` is a property of type `DbSet<Bill>`

`DbFunctions.TruncateTime` method is in `System.Data.Entity` namespace. So make sure you have a `using` statement to import that.

Comment: i can't call [(DbFunctions)

Comment: what you mean you can't call ? What is stopping you from doing so ?

Comment: Anonymous type property name shall be Date and solution also needs OrderBy clause

Comment: @MrinalKamboj The answer is primarly to show how to do the Group by ! SO is not a place to give pixel perfect code for someone to copy and paste ! Thanks for pointing out the OrderBy though, I will fix it

Comment: @bao4461826, check this, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220142(v=vs.113).aspx, you need namespace `System.Data.Entity`

Comment: @Shyju, that's your choice, since solution just didn't show how to GroupBy, it shows complete set of details, how to process the final result using anonymous type as an output of Select statement